# Email notification from AWS Cloudfomartion?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

How do I get this DNSRecord as an Email notification from CloudFormation?

```
"DNSRecord" : {
"Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
    "Properties" : {
        "HostedZoneName" : { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [{"Ref" : "HostedZoneName"}, "." ]]},
        "Name" : { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [{"Ref" : "RecordSetName"}, ".", {"Ref" : "HostedZoneName"}, "."]]},
        "Type" : "CNAME",
        "ResourceRecords" :[ { "Fn::ImportValue" : "DNSName" } ],
        "TTL" : "900"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS CloudFormation will not send an email, but your calling script could do so...

An AWS CloudFormation stack can produce [Outputs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html), such as the name of a DNS record created as part of the stack.

If you have automated the creation of a CloudFormation stack (eg you have a script that calls CloudFormation to trigger the stack creation), it can receive back the content of these outputs. Your script could then extract the desired information and send an email.

Alternatively, you could create an [AWS Lambda-backed Custom Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) that `dependsOn` the DNSRecord. You could then write a Lambda function that sends an email message.

**Bottom line:** No fully-automated method, but you could write your own.

Comment: You are saying that Script can send an email of CloudFormation output. What type of script it is?

Comment: The script is whatever you used to trigger CloudFormation to run. After it has done that, the same script takes the output and sends the email. You can write it in any programming language or scripting language (eg PowerShell, Bash), but it is up to you to write it.

Comment: Iam new to CloudFormation. Can you tell me how to get CloudFormation outputs through powershell and email it? Thank you

Comment: See [AWS Tools for PowerShell Cmdlet Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html) and [New-CFNStack Cmdlet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/New-CFNStack.html)

Comment: How do I get only **PhysicalResourceId** from `Get-CFNStackResources -StackName myStack -LogicalResourceId DNSRecord`

Comment: Feel free to start a new Question if you require assistance.

Comment: Just a small comment, instead of `DependsOn` with the custom resource, just use a Parameter for the custom resource and set it's value to the `DNSRecord` (via `Fn::GetAtt`).